# Sum of a geometric series $\sum_0^\infty \frac{1}{2^{1+2n}}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

$$\sum_0^\infty \frac{1}{2^{1+3n}}$$

So maybe I have written the sequence incorrectly, but how do I apply the $\frac{1}{1 - r}$ formula for summing a geometric sequence to this? When I do it I get something over one which is wrong because this is suppose to model a percentage of something.

Comment: I think you meant $$2^{1+2n}$$ in the body of your question

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Hint:**
write 
$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{2^{1+2n}} = \frac12 \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{2^{2n}} = \frac12 \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{4^{n}}
$$
and use the closed-form formula for geometric series.

Comment: I have no idea what you are talking about, why can't I apply the formula from my book?

Comment: You can: look at the last expression. $r=\frac{1}{4} \in[0,1)$, so you get $$\frac12\cdot\frac{1}{1-r} = \frac12\cdot\frac{1}{1-\frac14}=\frac12\cdot\frac{4}{3}=\frac23$$
To apply the "formula from your book", you need to have something of the form $\sum_{n=0}^\infty r^n$ with $|r| < 1$; so the main part is to *get* an expression of this type.

Comment: Actually your formula is wrong and it gives incorrect answers for 1, 2 and so on. It only works at n = 0.

Comment: What do you mean?
$$\frac12\cdot \frac{1}{4^n}=\frac{1}{2^{1+2n}}$$ for every $n\in\mathbb{N}$. From there,
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{2^{1+2n}}= \frac12 \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{4^{n}}=\frac12 \sum_{n=0}^\infty r^n=\frac12\frac{1}{1-r}$$ with $r\stackrel{\rm{}def}{=}{\frac14}$.

Comment: I don't know what the weird E or a hollow N means but I had the wrong formula in the post, it is fixed now.

Comment: Well, $\mathbb{N}$ is the set of natural integers, $\{0,1,2,\dots\}$. As for the edit you **just** made to the original question (in general, try to avoid changing what you ask after it's been answered several times!), try to generalize — observe that $$\frac{1}{2^{1+3n}}=\frac12\frac{1}{2^{3n}}=\frac12\frac{1}{8^n}$$, now. So $r=\frac18$ is the new ratio to use in the closed-form formula.

Comment: Is there some way I can memorize to transform these into a form with a single n? I would have to spend a while writting it out to figure out how to transform it.

Comment: See latest comment above (to @robjohn's answer).

Answer (score 6):

This is
$$
\begin{align}
\frac12\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac1{4^n}
&=\frac12\frac1{1-\frac14}\\
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Why? I have to write it like that? What "form" is that? This is what makes math so frustrating and arbitrary, I am given this infallible formula and I have to write a series out of some word problem so I do it, test point it and it works flawlessly  but it fails when I use the infallible formula. How do I know what form I have to morph my series into?

Comment: This "infaillible formula" only applies for expressions of the form $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty r^n$$ with $|r|<1$. If you have something slightly different, you must first massage it to get to this type of sum — otherwise, you just cannot apply the formula.

Comment: But I do have an r less than 1.

Comment: @PaulthePirate: as ClementC says, your formula applies to series of the form
$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty r^n=\frac1{1-r}
$$
where $|r|\lt1$. You need to get your series into that form to use the formula. We did that by factoring out $\frac12$ and writing $\frac1{2^{2n}}$ as $\frac1{4^n}=\left(\frac14\right)^n$.

Comment: But $\frac{1}{2^{1+2n}}$ is not of the form $r^n$ (it must be the case that $\frac{1}{2^{1+2n}}=r^n$ for any $n$).

Comment: Hmm, how is n defined? As a single term? n can't be 1+x or something? Only integers?

Comment: @PaulthePirate: $n$ is the index of the summation. It takes the values $0,1,2,3,4,5,\dots$ for each term of the summation.
$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty r^n=r^0+r^1+r^2+r^3+r^4+\dots
$$
just as
$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty r^{1+2n}=r^1+r^3+r^5+r^7+r^9+\dots
$$

Comment: @robjohn I understand that but for the formula the n can only be n not a multiple of n or anything?

Comment: @PaulthePirate: The formula says
$$
\frac1{1-r}=1+r+r^2+r^3+r^4+\dots
$$
for $|r|\lt1$. Just because the exponents are abstracted to an index $n$ does not mean they can be changed to other than what the summation notation assigns them.

Comment: @PaulthePirate: You can use the fact that $$r^{\alpha n+\beta}=(r^\alpha)^n\cdot r^\beta$$if you have a multiple of $n$ in the exponent. In particular, setting $R\stackrel{\rm{}def}{=}(r^\alpha)$, you go back to an expression of the form $r^\beta\cdot R^n$. So that $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty r^{\alpha n+\beta} = r^\beta\sum_{n=0}^\infty R^n$$

Answer (score 1):

Write $$S=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2^{1+2n}}=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2^3}+\frac{1}{2^5}+\cdots$$ Then note that $$\frac{S}{2^2}=S-\frac{1}{2}\Rightarrow S=\frac{\frac{1}{2}}{\frac{3}{4}}=\frac{2}{3}$$